# The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments for a class constructor (C#)

Tags: c#, class, constructor, overloading

I'm getting this error and not entirely sure why. In one class I create an object with the following line of code:

```
StoreSale sale = new StoreSale(1, 13.99);
```

The constructor inside the StoreSale class looks like this:

```
public StoreSale(int quantity, float value)
{
   this.quantity = quantity;
   this.value = value;
}
```

...and I'm getting the error 'The best overloaded method match for 'applicationname'.StoreSale.StoreSale(int, float) has some invalid arguments.'

Could anybody advise me as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Since you don't have a problem with int quantity = 1, the problem is obviously with the value of 13.99. The first line of your code does not look like a statement for a real runtime since the values are all hard-coded. Therefore, you could have easily done float value = 13.99; and have seen this error for yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`13.99` is a *double* literal. Append an `f` to make it a float: `13.99f`.

In any case, you probably don't want to use binary floating-point for monetary values anyway. `decimal` is a far saner choice.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Wasn't aware of the decimal data type or the necessity of appending an f to floats.

Comment: Joey is right that you should use decimal for monetary values. In that case, you'd also want to use `13.99m` for a decimal literal.

Answer (score 4):

`13.99` is a `double`. To make it a `float` literal add an `f`: `13.99f`.

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because the literal `13.99` is a `double`, and there is no implicit conversion from `double` to `float`. Use `13.99F` instead.

```
StoreSale sale = new StoreSale(1, 13.99F);
```